# Trouble with WordPress is_user_logged_in()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Here is my website: http://communitysupportedseafood.com/

I have a function that replaces the the WooCommerce price, if a user is not logged in, to "Login to See the Price."

This works fine until after a user logs in and goes back to the home page. The top bar still displays "Login" and the product prices display "Login to See the Price". This only happens on the homepage. If a user goes to any other pages, the top bar and prices display correctly.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening on the homepage?

Here is my function:

```
/* Users must login to see the price */
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html','members_only_price');
function members_only_price($price){
    if(is_user_logged_in() ){
        return $price;
    }
    else return '<a href="' . get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">Login</a> to see price!';
}
```

Comment: How do you "go back" ?

Comment: Do you have any caching plugins? Or through your host?

Comment: Hi, Yes I do have W3TC cache plugin enabled. Maybe adding an exception would help? I'm not too familiar with how to do that.